# Why JAVA Development Tools is used to refactor NOT JAVA files?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to create my own refactoring for my own type of files.
I figured out, that if I select in Eclipse Refactor-Rename on not Java file (for example on xsd file or any other file) then "Rename Resource" dialog show up.
The interesting thing is that org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RenameAction is used to show this dialog.

The question is - why **JAVA** Development Tools is used to rename **non-java** files?

The another question - may I reuse **org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RenameAction** to create my custom refactoring of my own type of file? Or I have to create my own **RenameAction**? I don't understand what should i learn to create my own "rename" refactoring - JDT or LTK or both or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is because I was using Java Perspective and "Package Explorer"
When using other perspective and "Navigator" JDT is not used, instead org.eclipse.ui.actions.RenameResourceAction is used what is pretty expected.